# Http 400. Bad request. When uploading xml file with special characters

Tags: xml, http, tomcat, jboss, bad-request

Maybe you can help me in my problem:) And here is the issue description.

My application is running on jboss 4.2.3. It has some functionality to upload content via rest endpoint. I have a problem when user tries to send content with special character like **&#x7;** . User always get 400 bad response.

Here is as example of body of PUT request that run ok:

```
<content-list xmlns="http://www.test.com/pgp/1.0">
  <content-record content-type="i_schema_2:ContentType2"  
  url-key="bla bla bla" created-by="test">
     <field name="field1" type="string">Field3 Value</field>
     <field name="field2" type="string">Field4 Value</field>
     <field name="field3" type="string">Field4 Value</field>
  </content-record>
</content-list>
```

And here is as example of body of PUT request that run with 400 error:

```
<content-list xmlns="http://www.test.com/pgp/1.0">
  <content-record content-type="i_schema_2:ContentType2"  
  url-key="bla bla bla" created-by="test">
     &#x7;<field name="field1" type="string">Field3 Value</field>
     <field name="field2" type="string">Field4 Value</field>
     <field name="field3" type="string">Field4 Value</field>
  </content-record>
</content-list>
```

Is this could be tuned by setting some options to tomcat of jboss or some http request header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&#x7;` is not a legal character in XML.  It sounds like your server is parsing the XML when it is uploaded, and the XML is not well-formed.

Comment: Yes, i see, i forgot that i'm using Spring @RequestBody.  I will look into docs of it.